# saga does not listen action dispatched from custom middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

The use case is I need to check if the token has been expired or not. If the token is expired then I need to call api to get new access token. Access token expires on every 30 minutes. For this what I tried to do is.

1. Write a custom middleware called `checkTokenExpirationMiddleware` on store.js
2. Dispatch `checkToken` action so that saga can catch that action and trigger an api call to get new access token.
3. Inject reducer and saga on app.js

The issue is saga could not listen that action.

Here is the code on what i did

store/index.js

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createInjectorsEnhancer, forceReducerReload } from "redux-injectors";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";

const checkTokenExpirationMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  console.log("#####action#####", action);
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
  if (token && jwt_decode(token).exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
    // dispatch checkToken action so that saga will listen this action
    // and call api for another access token
    const result = next(actions.checkToken());
    return result;
    // store.dispatch(actions.checkToken());
  }
  next(action);
};

export function configureAppStore() {
  const reduxSagaMonitorOptions = {};
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(reduxSagaMonitorOptions);
  const { run: runSaga } = sagaMiddleware;

  // // Create the store with saga middleware
  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, checkTokenExpirationMiddleware];

  const enhancers = [
    createInjectorsEnhancer({
      createReducer,
      runSaga,
    }),
  ];

  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: createReducer(),
    middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware(), ...middlewares],
    devTools:
      /* istanbul ignore next line */
      process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ||
      process.env.PUBLIC_URL.length > 0,
    enhancers,
  });

  // Make reducers hot reloadable, see http://mxs.is/googmo
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept("./reducers", () => {
      forceReducerReload(store);
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

store/globalSaga.js

```
export function* checkToken() {
  console.log("checkToken sagaå");
  debugger;
  // need to call api to get new access token
}

export function* globalSaga() {
  //  watches for
  console.log("global saga watcher");
  yield all([
    takeLatest(actions.logout, logout),
    takeEvery(actions.checkToken, checkToken),
  ]);
}
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  // const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log("injecting saga and reducer");
  useInjectReducer({ key: sliceKey, reducer });
  useInjectSaga({ key: sliceKey, saga: globalSaga });
  // React.useEffect(() => {
    // this executes saga
  //   console.log("dispatching");
  //   dispatch(actions.checkToken());
  // }, []);
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner />}>
      <Router>
        <RouterApp />
      </Router>
    </React.Suspense>
  );
}
```

why after dispatching `checkToken` action from middleware, the saga could not catch it?

Note: I am using reduxjs/toolkit.

UPDATE

I fetched api from here to get the new access token. Now i can get access token and there is no infinite loop. However there is a problem, it does not execute the api which was previously failed due to invalid token(expired). How can i now again execute that api after getting fresh access token?

```
const checkTokenExpirationMiddleware = ({ dispatch, getState }) => (
  next
) => async (action) => {
  const isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = getState()?.global
    .isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken;
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"));
  const access_token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
  if (
    !isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken &&
    access_token &&
    jwt_decode(access_token).exp < Date.now() / 1000
  ) {
    const payload = {
      data: {
        refresh_token: access_token,
      },
    };
    const response = await request(
      "https://localhost:3000/token/refresh",
      payload,
      "POST"
    );
    console.log("#########response#########", response);
    if (response?.status === 200) {
      localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response?.access_token));
      dispatch(actions.checkTokenSuccess());
      next(action); // now need to call the api with new access token which could not execute due to invalid token(expired)
      console.log("action dispatching", action);
    }
  }
  next(action);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because middleware form a pipeline, and [the `storeAPI.dispatch` and `next` functions do different things](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#is-it-ok-to-have-more-than-one-middleware-chain-in-my-store-enhancer-what-is-the-difference-between-next-and-dispatch-in-a-middleware-function)

- `storeAPI.dispatch(action)` sends the action to the *start* of the middleware chain, so it will go through all middleware (including this one)
   `next(action)` sends the action to the *next* middleware in the chain.

So, if you set things up as `applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, myCustomMiddleware)`, and your custom middleware calls `next(action)`, the action will go straight to the reducers and the saga middleware will never see it.

If you call `storeAPI.dispatch(action)` instead, it will go to the start of the middleware pipeline, which is `sagaMiddleware`.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation. Lucky to get explanation from redux maintainer :). I tried `store.dispatch(actions.checkToken())` but this creates an infinite loop and saga does not catches this action. Is there any problem in my setup?

Comment: Yes. Your custom middleware is _always_ trying to read the token from localStorage, and _always_ dispatching the action. You need to change that logic somehow so it doesn't keep dispatching every time.

Comment: Sorry, I could not fix yet. Can you help me where should i exactly change the logic?

Comment: I have updated my question with new code that i tried. This way there is no infinite loop issue. But api which was failed due to invalid token is not called after getting fresh access token.